# Synergy installer is unable to start service on Windows 10

Tags: windows, services, synergy, installer, privileges

When I try to install Synergy on Windows 10, it gives me this error: "Service 'Synergy' (Synergy) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services."

Synergy and the installer were built by myself.

How do I grant the installer the privileges to start the service?

Comment: Are you running the part that starts the service as admin?

Comment: I even tried running the whole installer as admin and it didn't work.

Comment: What happens if you do `sc start synergy` from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: Ah, then it's not actually a permissions problem. The service is failing to start (or doesn't communicate with the SCM). If it produces logs, please post them.